# Deterministic finite automata (DFA) (have odd length or end with aaa)

Tags: automata, finite-automata

Is my attempt is true or where am I wrong?

DFA : The set of strings over $\{a, b\} $ that have odd length or end with $aaa$.

[image: My attempt]

Comment: Did you try finding a smaller automaton?

Comment: @k.stm Yes, I tried but I couldn't find.Is this true?

Comment: Haven’t checked it. Actually, you probably *do* need eight states. Have you tried organizing them? Can you tell us what each of the states $1$, …, $8$ describe? (Oh, you have nine states – I think you can toss one.)

Comment: @k.stm there are 8 states.It is hard to describe what each of states describe.

Comment: It looks correct to me, but the best thing to do is to run it in your computer

Answer (score 1):

Your automaton is correct but it is not minimal. The minimal automaton only has 5 states. Actually, you can obtain it by minimising your automaton. You will then identify states 2 and 4, states 3 and 5 and states 6 and 8.

Comment: Of states $1$ and $4$, only one is an accepting state,so identifying them will lead to an inequivalent automaton. You mean $2$ and $4$, I presume.

Comment: The empty word neither has odd length nor ends in $\mathtt {aaa}$.

Comment: There are two states 1 in the picture. Let us call $0$ the initial state to avoid any confusion.

Comment: No, the initial state is $1$, the other one is a $2$.

Comment: OK, let me correct my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Your DFA is correct; it consists of eight states, as you have, one for every combination of "Is the string odd or even length?" and "Have I most recently seen 0,1,2, or 3+ consecutive A's"?  You can arrange your DFA like this for easier readability:

[image]

And there's an equivalent DFA with fewer states that might be easier to check:
[image]